# New Line or Carriage Return not working in C code

Tags: c

I'm attempting to write a program using the GCC (v. 4.7) compiler on Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm running into the issue of the new line "/n" or the carriage "/r" not working in my programs. And I've tried opening the created file in different text editors and I get the same result.
Here is the program.

```
main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int i;
    fp = fopen("/home/evan/Desktop/Numberlist.txt", "w");
    for(i;i<100;i++){
        fprintf(fp, "%d /n", i);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

And here is how the output looks.

```
0 /n1 /n2 /n3 /n4 /n5 /n6 /n7 /n8 /n9 /n10 /n11 /n12 /n13 /n14 /n15 /n16 /n17 /n18 /n19 /n20 /n21 /n22 /n23 /n24 /n25 /n26 /n27 /n28 /n29 /n30 /n31 /n32 /n33 /n34 /n35 /n36 /n37 /n38 /n39 /n40 /n41 /n42 /n43 /n44 /n45 /n46 /n47 /n48 /n49 /n50 /n51 /n52 /n53 /n54 /n55 /n56 /n57 /n58 /n59 /n60 /n61 /n62 /n63 /n64 /n65 /n66 /n67 /n68 /n69 /n70 /n71 /n72 /n73 /n74 /n75 /n76 /n77 /n78 /n79 /n80 /n81 /n82 /n83 /n84 /n85 /n86 /n87 /n88 /n89 /n90 /n91 /n92 /n93 /n94 /n95 /n96 /n97 /n98 /n99 /n
```

It is actually printing the carriage return into the program instead of starting a new line after every number. And I also tried doing the standard printf to print in the command prompt instead of to a text file and it does the same thing there.
Any ideas?

Comment: It may be because you are _not_ printing a newline (which is `'\n'`). Notice the difference between backslash ("\" which is correct) and forward slash ("/").

Answer (score 2):

The backslash is used for escaping `\` use `fprintf(fp, "%d \n", i);`